# Magento Invalid method isStateProvinceRequired

Tags: shipping, magento-1

I am receiving following error when i put a product into the shopping cart and go to the shopping cart i am receiving following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:88:"Invalid method Amasty_Shiprules_Block_Cart_Shipping::isStateProvinceRequired(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:3968:"
app/design/frontend/vitacatalog/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml(42): Varien_Object->__call('isStateProvince...', Array)
app/design/frontend/vitacatalog/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml(42): Amasty_Shiprules_Block_Cart_Shipping->isStateProvinceRequired()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/checkvit/...')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/vitaca...')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('shipping', true)
app/design/frontend/vitacatalog/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml(127): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('shipping')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/checkvit/...')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/vitaca...')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
app/design/frontend/vitacatalog/default/template/page/1column.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/checkvit/...')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/vitaca...')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(181): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
{main}";s:3:"url";s:15:"/checkout/cart/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I have checked the required state provinces in the backend but still getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the module `Amasty_Shiprules` overrides `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping` but lacks the method `isStateProvinceRequired()` of the original class. This method has been there since forever, so a mere compatibility issue with your Magento version is unlikely.

Uninstall the module that causes the bug and/or contact Amasty for support.